# Children of XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

How do I get just the children of an XElement?

I am currently using the XElement.Descendants() function, which returns all levels of XElements, rather than just the child nodes.

What I would really like is an IEnumerable of just the children.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The immediate child elements of one [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) are accessible by calling the [`Element()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) or [`Elements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.elements.aspx) functions. Use the overloads with a name to access specific elements, or without to access all child elements.

There are also similar methods like [`Attribute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute.aspx) and [`Attributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attributes.aspx) that you might find useful.

Comment: This seems to have solved the OPs question but there is no parameterless overload for `Element()` so this doesn't help me to get the first child when I know that its `XName` can vary.

Comment: If you just want the first child, reguardless of name, try using `Elements().FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Why couldn't they have just called it "XElement.Children"? Way more discoverable.

Comment: @Tacroy Each XElement has two sets of children, either of which may be empty. One is the ordered set of child *elements*, the other is a set of child *attributes* - whichever one you think should be found in *Children*, others would disagree. Using `Elements` and `Attributes` follows the nomenclature of the Xml standard.

Comment: @Bevan I think the better answer would be that there may also be a set of **nodes**, each of which might not be an element. Attributes are not actually children of the element.

Answer (score 13):

XElement.Nodes() should get you what you want.

If you just want the XElement child nodes then you might need to restrict it (depending on your XML) with:

```
XElement.Nodes().OfType<XElement>()
```

Answer (score 4):

[XElement.Nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.nodes.aspx)