# Get child elements from XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Children of XElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486912/children-of-xelement)

I want to get child elements from XElement using C#. How can this be done?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try [`.Elements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx) :

```
XElement element = GetElement();
var children = element.Elements();
```

If you want elements from all levels, you may also have a look at [`Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendants.aspx).

Answer (score 38):

There are a few alternatives to navigate from an `XElement` to its children:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> allChildElements = xElement.Elements();
IEnumerable<XElement> specificChildElements = xElement.Elements("tag");
XElement firstSpecificChildElement = xElement.Element("tag");
```